# Maven: set release and latest xml tags in the maven-metadata.xml when running mvn install

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am trying to figure out how install a dependency into my local .m2 directory and add the "latest" and "release" tags to the maven-metadata.xml file that is generated when the mvn install command is ran.

**Example**: below is what's currently happening. Running `mvn install` will put the dependency into my local .m2 directory but is does not generate the maven-metdata.xml with the "latest" or "release" tags with the specified version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
    <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo-bar</artifactId>
    <versioning>
        <versions>
            <version>0.0.0.20-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20171207212617</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

**Example of what I would like to accomplish is below**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
    <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo-bar</artifactId>
    <versioning>
        <latest>0.0.0.20-SNAPSHOT</latest>
        <release>0.0.0.20-SNAPSHOT</release>
        <versions>
             <version>0.0.0.20-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </versions>
        <lastUpdated>20171207212617</lastUpdated>
    </versioning>
</metadata>
```

I want this so in the pom file that I plan on using this dependency I can specify the version as "RELEASE" or "LATEST" is maven will pull appropriate version, this way applications don't have to worry about explicitly defining the version in the pom.xml. I am using Maven v3.5.0.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. If more information is needed to do not hesitate to ask. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maven is not responsible for setting `<latest>` for anything but Maven Plugins. `<latest>` could be set for ordinary artifacts by repository manager. E.g. you can open Nexus, right click on a hosted repository and ask it to Rebuild Metadata.

`<release>` is usually not set by Maven as well. While it's possible to force Maven to set it via `mvn install -DupdateReleaseInfo=true` - this really is more for local testing of maven plugins.

Many people who start doing some CI or CD work think in terms of latest artifacts. This is a very common mistake. In general it's recommended to always use strict versions instead of ranges/LATEST/RELEASE/-SNAPSHOT which could resolve in one artifact today and in another artifact tomorrow. This makes your workflow less predictable and reproducible.

If you *really* want to rely on latest (which again is a *bad* idea), you can simply use `0.0.0.20-SNAPSHOT` version or leverage ranged versions.

Comment: I've tried using the arg -DupdateReleaseInfo=true but that didn't seem to work. I'm not familiar with Nexus repository manager but I will definitely check it out. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Apart from the above said using `RELEASE` or `LATEST` will produce a warning with the [most recent Maven version (3.5.2)](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.2/release-notes.html)...